# Simple rewrite rule not running in on Apache 2.2.15 with AllowOveride All

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Just a gross error check - 
In httpd.conf under we have

```
<DIRECTORY />
    AllowOveride All
</DIRECTORY>
```

In htaccess we have:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^dir/?$ http://internal.url/dir/ [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Internally http://internal.url/dir/ shows the correct web page.

However via apache the rewrite rule just gives a 404

Can you guys think of any reasons for this?

The rewrite base is / so it has been left out.

=================================

Update, I have just been forwarded the httpd.conf:

```
<Directory />
     Options FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride All
</Directory>


<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

And some v hosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
Include htaccess/x/*
RewriteLog "url.log"
RewriteLogLevel 2
ProxyRequests off
ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/
ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/
ProxyPreserveHost On
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:81>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
Redirect permanent /d/WAYN http://url/WAYN/
Include htaccess/w/*
RewriteLog "/var/log/httpd/url.log"
RewriteLogLevel 2
ProxyRequests off
ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/
ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/
ProxyPreserveHost On
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Do you have mod_rewrite loaded?

Comment: Yup:
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so